# how to send jsonp request to server in sencha 2.0

Tags: sencha-touch

I will get this error Repeatedly

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ajax.php

> {"error":"Server Error</b>: Method file_get_contents unable to open request body!"}

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({

                   url: 'http://yaksee.com/facebook/ajax.php',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        params: {

                           format: 'json',


        },
        success: function(result) {





            if (result) {

        alert('success');

                     alert(result);

            } else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'There was an error retrieving the weather.');
            }


        }
    });
}},
```

Comment: -1, your server side is throwing an error, has nothing to do with Sencha Touch.

Comment: thanks for your reply .           is really an api key is needed to send a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have to disable the Browser's web security

Then it will be ok

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example which works : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP

I changed it to your URL and it stopped working in this [fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#p8JzP) so it seems like issue with webservice or it requires some more data to make request because it is returning HTTP 200 status but with some custom error message